# Map SQL type to import wizard types

Tags: sql, csv, import, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a table showing how SQL Server 2008's types map to the Data Types in its own Import wizard? For example `varchar` maps to `DT_STR`, what does `bigint` map to?

I'm talking about this wizard:
[image: SQL2008 Import Wizard]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use `DT_I8` for `bigint`.

More : [SSIS Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx) on section : Mapping of Integration Services Data Types to Database Data Types

Comment: This is more or less what I was looking for, thanks! Yeah, I went with `DT_I8` on a hunch and it worked fine.